# How to Get the current VPN Windows Identity

Tags: .net, identity, vpn

I have a console application that calls a WCF service on a remote domain.  The WCF service is uses Windows credential type for the transport and message credential types.

The WCF service is configured to negotiate for the user's credentials.

My question is how can I obtain the identity object that the WCF service uses on the client side?

For example, I am logged into my computer `"LocalMachine\Garry"`.  I connect to my company's VPN with the `"MyCompany\Garry"` domain name.

The WCF service is located on my company's domain.  When I execute the WCF service from my computer, based on the negotiation, the WCF service uses the `"MyCompany\Garry"` identity.

In the WCF service - `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`
 - returns `"MyCompany\Garry"`.

In the console app - `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`
 - returns `"LocalMachine\Garry"`.

How can I get the VPN domain identity that is passed to the WCF service?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, I never found a solution :(

Comment: Did you found solution by now?